# Vertica: Subquery OR and co related tables error

Tags: sql, vertica

**Model Data**

[image]

**Revenue Table**

[image]

I'm trying to find out my model performance that is I had given a score of 0.001 for a Product Category A in the model_month of May (5) for the Model_year(2015) now to track the performance i'm tracking the revenue.

I claim to say that the model numbers are valid for 3 months so to check the performance i want to see a new coloumn next to model table with 3 months revenue after the model_month.

```
SELECT a.*,
case    when (a.MODEL_MONTH<10 ) then   (select sum(b.net_revenue) from Revenue as b
                                        where ((b.cal_month > a.MODEL_MONTH OR  b.cal_month<a.MODEL_MONTH+4) AND b.cal_year=a.MODEL_YEAR)
                                                    and a.model_BU=b.prodcat a.model_region=b.hp_region)

        when (a.MODEL_MONTH>=10) then   (select sum(b.net_revenue) from Revenue b
                                        where (((b.cal_month > a.MODEL_MONTH and b.cal_year=a.MODEL_YEAR) || 
                                                (b.cal_month < a.MODEL_MONTH-9 and b.cal_year=a.MODEL_YEAR+1)) AND a.model_BU=b.prodcat))
        ELSE '0'
        END as Net_Revenue

        FROM ModelData as a
        limit 10        
        ;
```

i'm getting errors as 
Error: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Non-equality correlated subquery expression is not supported
SQLState:  HY000
ErrorCode: 4160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

As you can read in the Vertica Documentation:

Analysing Data Guide > Writing Queries > Subqueries > Subquery Restrictions:

> Multiple correlations are allowed only for subqueries that are joined with an **equality** predicate

General info about [Correlated Subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)

Comment: Is there a turn around how to do this in a efficient way.

Comment: There are different possibilities depending your sla and data volumes. Being a select on a single table i'd initially use self joins. Run Vertica's DBD to improve Projection design for speed.